# c++0x library availability in any compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11

The standard will doubtless take years to put in place, which stinks because it looks great.  But I was reading it, and at least the library additions (hash maps in particular) would be really useful right away.  I noticed in the g++ docs that I can get 4.3 or better and use a flag to request the new features, whatever exists, but I was wondering if there is any way to just get the library.  And the fact that lots of the best boost stuff is now built in is really great, finally a decent random number facility built in!

So, are there any compilers which I can use right now which have a reasonably complete library in place, even if it can't use some of the cool new language features like auto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC with option `-std=c++0x` already covers a pretty good subset of C++0x. Version 4.4 is already pretty usable, 4.6 even moreso. It's missing template aliases, but many extremely useful language features as well as a very large part of the library is there and fully functional.

Here is the [full feature list](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: thanks, I saw 4.6 on a list and wasn't sure that was even out! I'll have to download it today.  I know there is another question there -- I've had problems installing a 4.6 compiler in addition to the one in the system....

Comment: @Dov: I've build my own version of GCC 4.6 on a variety of Linuxes and MacOSX (both as root and non-root) with no problems. Just get the requisite libraries (GMP, MPFR, MPC), configure with a `--prefix`, and `make install`. I found it very straightforward! (While you're at it you might try 4.7, too!)

Comment: I had a problem running it after it built itself, but it turns out that some of the libraries had been put into /opt/tools/lib and some into /opt/tools/lib64, so it was just a matter of putting both into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  4.5.1 works great, and I'm going to install 4.6 or 4.7 while I'm at it.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the standard library extensions, you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_tr1.html). The new standard library enhancements were mainly inspired by Boost libraries anyway.

As for supporting compilers, Visual Studio 2010 [supports a subset of the C++11 standard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx), GCC has [currently the best support for C++11](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and Clang is also [adopting the new standard](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). Don't know about other compilers but I think they will soon follow.

Comment: Pretty much this- the new libs are mostly found in Boost.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from GCC in `-std=c++0x` mode with its default libstdc++ on all platforms supported by GCC, you can also use LLVM's `libc++`, which works well on Linux/BSD/Mac, but hasn't been ported yet to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

GCC/libstdc++ has most of the library in place, but may require prepending `tr1/` to the include paths (`#include <tr1/unordered_map>` for hashed maps). It also puts the new library stuff in the namespace `std::tr1` instead of just `std`.

(TR1 stands for Technical Report 1, which was a report describing the library additions for C++0x.)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the libraries, and in particular the one you mention here (unordered_map) were defined as part of a technical review back in 2003, and have been moved to the C++0x standard mainly unmodified. Most compilers have the TR1 libraries implemented in the `std::tr1` namespace.

Other libraries were pulled from other sources, Boost being a big source of libs for the upcoming standard (`function`, `bind`, `thread`...), but that depends on what you want to add to your project.

As to whether you can extract the libraries from a C++0x and use them in a non-c++0x compiler, you most probably cannot do it, as they will make use of the newer features (think move constructors), and that will fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link where you can find c++0x support for most of the compilers

http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

The list gets updated whenever a new c++0x support is added.
As you can see g++ has the support of maximum number of C++0x features as of now.